# I am getting garbage values for this prob in c

Tags: c

I am trying to execute the code below, but along with my answer I am getting some garbage values. Please help me find where I made an error.

```
int main()
{
    int n,i,j,k=0;
    int a[100];
    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
        {
            a[++k]=i;
        }
    }
    for(j=0;a[j]!='\0';j++)
    {
         printf("\t%d",a[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Clearly `a[0]` will be printed out as garbage, may be others too, check your indices, if you enter nothing for those in `a`, you get "garbage" values

Comment: You do know that things start at zero. i.e. `for(i=1;i<=n;i++)` possibly be `for(i=0;i<n;++i)`

Answer (score 2):

```
 int a[100];
```

C does not initialize the array elements by default. So all the elements that are not assigned in your first loop will have garbage.

What you can do is:

```
 int a[100] = {0};
```

This will initialize all elements to `0`

Answer (score 1):

In C array indexing starts from `0`. Preincrement `++k` will cause to start array indexing from `1`. Change it to `k++`. Also change

```
 for(j=0;a[j]!='\0';j++)
```

to

```
 for(j=0;j < k;j++)
```

to print the only values you have entered.
your code should be

```
 for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    if(n%i==0)
    {
        a[k++]=i;
    }
}
for(j=0; j < k;j++)
{
     printf("\t%d",a[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here how you can fix this. Next time please describe what you were trying to achive